# Extracting data from files in multiple directories

Tags: bash, shell-script, perl, raspberry-pi

I am new to perl and I am trying to create a perl script (or bash script) which can extract the word "Hello World" from files with .txt extension in multiple directories. To make it more clear, suppose my script is placed in the directory "/home/pi/A" which has sub directories - Folder, Temp, Document (Directories are unknown to me it is just an example).
The directory /home/pi/A/Folder has a .txt file and /home/pi/Temp has also have a .txt file so on..
Here is my code

```
 #!/usr/bin/perl -w

 opendir(DIR, ".");
 @files = grep(/\.txt$/,readdir(DIR));
 closedir(DIR);

 foreach $file (@files) {
    print "$file\n";
}
```

The output should be

```
Hello World  
Hello World
Hello World
So on...
```

Comment: `grep -r 'hello world' somedir`

Comment: I have a list of unknown directories

Comment: It's recursive, in your example `somedir` would be `A`.

Comment: Ok how will I find the .txt file. Extract with grep i got that part, sort of confused

Comment: for specific files, `grep --include='*.txt' -r 'Hello World' /path/to/dir` ... use `-i` for case-insensitive search, `-F` if search term is not regex, would be faster

Answer (score 2):

It will find the .txt file from a directory A and check whether it has the word "hello world"

```
find A -type f -name "*.txt" -exec grep -h "hello world" {} +
```

Comment: thanks, but I am getting the directory along with whole text in the txt file not only "hello world"

Comment: can you modify your post and let us know the directory structure and the expected output. so we can help

Comment: Ok i have updated it, but /home/pi/A/  also consist of other 14 folders which contain txt files. It hard to show all 17 folders. Also I tried your code but I am getting path then the result. I just want the result ,thanks

Comment: just use -h option in grep. it will ignore the file name.